# pandas: Is it possible to boxplot a groupby of multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, group-by, boxplot

I'm aware that one can groupby a single column, then boxplot to get one subplot for each group like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'A', 1], ['A', 'B', 2], ['B', 'A', 3]], columns=['ca', 'cb', 'v'])

df.groupby('ca').boxplot(column='v')
```

But when you try to groupby more columns, it fails with a cryptic message that it can't find the grouped values in the index:

```
df.groupby(['ca', 'cb']).boxplot(column='v')

# "None of [Index(['A', 'A'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

It actually manages to draw the right number of subplots and plot the first one, but fails after that.

I’m aware you can do this by making a derived column from the columns you want grouped, e.g. by concatenating them all string-wise, but is there a cleaner way to do this? Is boxplot just not possible with nested groupby?

I'm using pandas 1.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that if you get rid of the argument `column='v'` and instead pass the argument `subplots=False`, the plot renders, but I don't know why this only works after the inclusion of subplots=False. I also would expect `df.groupby(['ca', 'cb']).boxplot(column='v')` to run without an error.

```
df.groupby(['ca','cb']).boxplot(subplots=False)
```

[image]

Comment: That's interesting, so boxplot does handle nested groups, might just be a bug in the subplot routines. I'll bring it up with the library authors and see what they say.

Comment: that's a good idea – there are a few open bug reports specifically related to pandas groupby and boxplots, but i think the issue you noticed has not been raised

Comment: Turns out someone raised this [back in 2016](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14701) with the same behavior, although I just tried in 1.5.2 and now get `pandas.errors.IndexingError: Too many indexers` instead. More explicit at least, I'll see if a fix is straightforward.